Rust compilation error: Actix falling back to a wrong version
I'm trying to bring back to life a small project I had a year and a half ago: a tiny, simple app for adding book reviews, quotes between books, relationships... it was my first ever (and only) Rust app, and it was a simple API for managing these types of objects in any type of database.
Now I'm trying to build the project, and I'm having some issues. I updated dependencies, and now I'm facing a strange error in which Actix is trying to fall back to an old version that is no longer supported in my project.
This is the specific error I get when I use cargo build:
error[E0277]: cannot subtract `TimeDelta` from `Tm`
   --> C:\Users\zerok\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\actix-http-1.0.1\src\cookie\jar.rs:224:44
    |
224 |             cookie.set_expires(time::now() - Duration::days(365));
    |                                            ^ no implementation for `Tm - TimeDelta`
    |
    = help: the trait `Sub<TimeDelta>` is not implemented for `Tm`
    = help: the following other types implement trait `Sub<Rhs>`:
              `Tm` implements `Sub<time::Duration>`
              `Tm` implements `Sub`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> C:\Users\zerok\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\actix-http-1.0.1\src\cookie\mod.rs:736:40
    |
736 |         self.set_expires(time::now() + twenty_years);
    |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Duration`, found `TimeDelta`

As you can see, some crate (no idea which) is trying to compile this code, which apparently just doesn't work. This is how my cargo.toml looks like:
[package]
name = "rust_web_server"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "2.0.3", features = ["sqlite", "r2d2", "returning_clauses_for_sqlite_3_35"] }
dotenvy = "0.15"
actix-web = "4"
actix-web-httpauth = { git = "https://github.com/actix/actix-web-httpauth" }
chrono = { version = "0.4.10", features = ["serde"] }
derive_more = "0.99.2"
futures = "0.3.1"
r2d2 = "0.8.8"
serde = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"
serde_json = "1.0"
alcoholic_jwt = "1.0.0"
reqwest = "0.9.22"
actix-rt = "2.7.0"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
tokio-test = "0.4.2"
actix-service = { version = "2.0.2" }

[dependencies.uuid]
version = "1.3.0"
features = [
    "v4",
    "fast-rng"
]

At this point, I tried many things that ChatGPT suggested, but nothing seems to work. This error keeps appearing every time I try to build the project. Any idea on what's wrong here?

You can use cargo tree -i actix-http@1.0.1 to see the chain of dependencies that is relying on that problem crate. 1.0.1 is quite old and that git dependency looks suspicious

A possible quick fix is to delete Cargo.lock and let cargo rebuild it from Cargo.toml using up-to-date versions.

@kmdreko I can see that actix-web-2.0.0 is using it as a dependency, which doesn't seem to make much sense. Also, awc v1.0.1. Should I delete these dependencies and download actix again from scratch?
